# Android Debugging techniques

Tags: android, memory

My question is there is a way to debug a specific line of code to check how much memory it takes or a technique of figuring out how much it uses?.

Note* I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See
 http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html
and
http://macgyverdev.blogspot.de/2011/07/profiling-android-application-tutorial.html

that's all you need to know ;)

Debugging and Profiling are the keywords.

Comment: Yup thanks, I was also debugging blindly and you helped me out thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be great if they change the system so I can accept immediately. 7 minutes too long tend to forget.